# Memory leak after refactoring `compactMap` for RxSwift.Observable from closure to function

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, rx-swift

I found a probable leak in my code because of a unit test which tests whether a dependency is called at `deinit`:

```
func testDeinit_ShouldStopMinutesTicker() throws {
    let minutesTicker = MockMinutesTicker(elapsedTicksAfterStart: [(), (), ()])
    var viewModel: AppointmentViewModel? = createAppointmentViewModel(minutesTicker: minutesTicker)
    viewModel = nil
    
    XCTAssertTrue(minutesTicker.isStopCalled)
}
```

This test is usually green. But when I refactored this:

```
func selectAppointment(index: Int) {
    selectedCellParamRelay.accept(index)
}

private func setupCellParamSelection() {
    selectedCellParamRelay
        .withLatestFrom(sortedCellParams) { ($0, $1) }
        .compactMap { [weak self] index, cellParams in
            guard let `self` = self,
                  let selectedParam = cellParams[safe: index],
                  self.isUpcomingAppointment(selectedParam) else { return nil }
            
            return selectedParam
            
        }
        .bind(to: upcomingCellParamRelay)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Into this:

```
func selectAppointment(index: Int) {
    selectedCellParamRelay.accept(index)
}

private func setupCellParamSelection() {
    selectedCellParamRelay
        .withLatestFrom(sortedCellParams) { ($0, $1) }
        .compactMap(selectAppointment(index:from:))
        .bind(to: upcomingCellParamRelay)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

private func selectAppointment(
    index: Int,
    from cellParams: [AppointmentCellParam]
) throws -> AppointmentCellParam? {
    guard let selectedParam = cellParams[safe: index],
          isUpcomingAppointment(selectedParam) else { return nil }

    return selectedParam
}

private func isUpcomingAppointment(_ appointment: AppointmentCellParam) -> Bool {
    return appointment.status != .missed && appointment.status != .finished
}
```

It becomes red and the `deinit` is not called at all.

The `setupCellParamSelection` func is being called from the `init` to setup the event handler for selecting any appointment cell by index. The `sortedCellParams` is a relay that is emitted by a dependency that in turn will get the values from the backend.

Can you help me figure out what went wrong with the second code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because `.compactMap(selectAppointment(index:from:))` needs to hold `self` in order to call `selectAppointment` even though the function doesn't need self.

The solution here is to move `isUpcomingAppointment(_:)` and `selectAppointment(index:from:)` outside of the class or as static functions within the class.

Comment: I thought the `self` was hold weakly because in the function definition itself it was like this: `compactMap<Result>(_ transform: @escaping (Element) throws -> Result?)` ? Maybe the `@escaping` keyword doesn't work like I assume it to be. I think I need to learn some more. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, because I had assumed that the `self` was already weak, I had refactored a lot with these kind of closures lately. It's a good thing that I was testing for deinitialization in this case. Because most of the other ones were not. So I think I need to hunt for similar codes in the project. I already feel tired thinking about it. LOL.

Comment: I found some explanation of this here: https://forums.swift.org/t/passing-func-as-func-arg-retains-self/33102/14

Answer (score 0):

On top of the accepted answer: CompactMap itself seems to leak:

```
override func subscribe(observer: AnonymousObserver<Result>) -> Disposable {
    let disposable1 = super.subscribe(observer: observer)
    let disposable2 = source.subscribe(
        onNext: {
            guard let mappedElement = self.transform($0) else { return }
            self.dispatch(event: .next(mappedElement))
        },
```